# Move Files from one directory to another using SSIS Package in Azure Data Lake Store Gen1

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am creating SSIS package and planning to use ADF to run it.

I am using Azure Data Lake Gen1 as File Store.

And as per our process once a file load completed we will move the file from one directory to another into Data Lake.

But not able to find anything in SSIS to do it. Anyone have any idea about it.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what's the thing you want to find? How the SSIS package works in Data Factory?

Comment: Is the source directory in data lake or is it on-premise? If everything is in datalake, I suggest you just use ADF to do it - don't use SSIS. If you _must_ use SSIS, you can use the SSIS Azure Feature Pack https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/azure-data-lake-store-file-system-task?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid For the time being it's kind of must to use SSIS, and yes I am using SSIS Azure Feature Pack to handle files from Data Lake but their's no option to move files in Data Lake.

Comment: @LeonYue We will deploy the SSIS package in ADF using (Configure SSIS Integration)

Comment: Please make it clear: are you trying to move a file from one folder to another in data lake? From my understanding this is a rename function. There are a number of API

Comment: ......you can call to do this, which can be called from SSIS in varying ways

Comment: For example here's the powershell command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/move-azurermdatalakestoreitem?view=azurermps-6.13.0 and here's the REST API command http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Rename_a_FileDirectory Both of these can be called from SSIS (with difficulty)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, trying to move files and Thanks for sharing those command. Trying if PowerShell script can be used in SSIS or not, Although if you have any idea how to execute it, that will be great.

Comment: Yes. Powershell, REST can be used in SSIS with difficulty. The point is that SSIS is not the right tool for this so introducing the constraint upfront is going to make it difficult. Actually the main difficulty is authentication. I take it you are using AAD authentication into DL (and it's DataLake Gen1 right?) ? This is likely to be far easier to do in an ADF pipeline than using ADF to run an SSIS package that is probably not going to be able to do AAD authentication

Comment: @PrabirS If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in comment, you will deploy the SSIS package in ADF using (Configure SSIS Integration).

You can reference this document to [Provision the Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure#provision-an-azure-ssis-integration-runtime).

This tutorial provides steps for using the Azure portal to provision an Azure-SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) Integration Runtime (IR) in Azure Data Factory (ADF). Azure-SSIS IR supports running packages deployed into SSIS catalog (SSISDB) hosted by Azure SQL Database server/Managed Instance (Project Deployment Model) and those deployed into file systems/file shares/Azure Files (Package Deployment Model). Once Azure-SSIS IR is provisioned, you can then use familiar tools, such as SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)/SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), and command line utilities, such as dtinstall/dtutil/dtexec, to deploy and run your packages in Azure.

1. [Create an Azure-SSIS integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure#create-an-azure-ssis-integration-runtime)
2. [Provision an Azure-SSIS integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure#provision-an-azure-ssis-integration-runtime)
3. [Deploy SSIS packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure#deploy-ssis-packages)

After you have created and configured the Azure-SSIS integration runtime, about how to run your SSIS package in Data Factory, Data Factory also give us so many ways:

1. [Execute SSIS packages in Azure from SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-ssdt)
2. [Run an SSIS package with the Execute SSIS Package activity in Azure
   Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-ssis-activity)
3. [Run an SSIS package with the Stored Procedure activity in Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-stored-procedure-activity)

Just choose the one which you like.

Hope this helps.